# TensorFlow keeping shape the same when slicing?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to take out a single element out of one dimension, while keeping the shapes the same.

The shape of the tensor is: `(BATCH_SIZE, N_STEPS, NUM_FEATURES)`
I want to create a new tensor that is `(BATCH_SIZE, 1, NUM_FEATURES)`, where 1 is the final step.

The input tensor shape is `(None, 128,16)` 
I tried to create a new tensor with the following:

```
X = X[:,-1,:]
```

X's shape becomes `(None, 16)` , but I need this to be `(None, 1,16)`

Answer (score 0):

Update: I got this to work with the following code:

```
s = tf.shape(X)
X = tf.reshape(X[:,-1,:],shape=[s[0],1,s[2]])
```